# undefined control sequence in a table

Tags: tables, errors, undefined

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{etex}

\usepackage[left=2.50cm,right=2.50cm,top=2.50cm,bottom=2.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amscd,amsbsy,array,color,epsfig}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,framed,latexsym,multicol,pstricks,slashed,xcolor}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
    \begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c||c|c|c||c|c|}
    \hline
        $P$ & $Q$ & $P \Rightarrow Q$ & $\neg P$ & $\neg Q$ & $(\neg Q) \Rightarrow (\neg P)$ & $Q \Rightarrow P$ \\
    \hline
        $T$ & $T$ & $T$ & $F$ & $F$ & $T$ & $T$ \\
    \hline
        $T$ & $F$ & $F$ & $F$ & $T$ & $F$ & $T$ \\
    \hline
        $F$ & $T$ & $T$ & $T$ & $F$& $T$ & $F$ \\
    \hline
        $F$ & $F$ & $T$ & $T$ & $T$ & $T$ & $T$ \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{\emph{Truth Table for $P \Rightarrow Q$, $(\neg Q) \Rightarrow (\neg P),$ and $Q \Rightarrow P.$}}
\end{table}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Hopefully I have given enough information in the MWE, because in my original I have a preamble, a table of contents, a chapter 0 (from which the table comes), and an analysis file which has the previous as inputs. So, I **might** have left something out that is needed from the MWE for it to compile.

But when I compile I get the following error at the beginning of the table:

```
Not in outer par mode \begin{table}[!ht]
Undefined control sequence \begin{table}[!ht]
Missing number, treated as zero \begin{table}[!ht]
```

Thanks.

Comment: $\imp$ is my shorthand for $\Rightarrow$ and the table is within a \begin{proof} and \end{proof} environment. I did not know how to edit my post. Sorry.

Comment: Never mind for some reason I did not see the "edit" button earlier.

Comment: `\usepackage{amsthm}` is missing if `proof` is used (or alternatively `\usepackage{mathtools}`. I don't think that your really need the `etex` package nowadays any longer. Also don't use the outdated `epsfig` package

Comment: I am using ntheorem. Sorry I knew I failed to include something. OK thanks!

Comment: unrelated to the question but `etex` and `epsfig` packages shouldn't be used in current documents (not since 1994 in the case of `epsfig`)

Comment: please fix the example in the question so that it generates the errors shown, otherwise it's not really possible to help.

Answer (score 1):

An attempt:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{etex}

\usepackage[left=2.50cm,right=2.50cm,top=2.50cm,bottom=2.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amscd,amsbsy,array,color,epsfig}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,framed,latexsym,multicol,pstricks,slashed,xcolor}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{amsthm}% PS

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
$\,$ %PS (some text [invisible])
%    \begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c||c|c|c||c|c|}
    \hline
        $P$ & $Q$ & $P \Rightarrow Q$ & $\neg P$ & $\neg Q$ & $(\neg Q) \Rightarrow (\neg P)$ & $Q \Rightarrow P$ \\
    \hline
        $T$ & $T$ & $T$ & $F$ & $F$ & $T$ & $T$ \\
    \hline
        $T$ & $F$ & $F$ & $F$ & $T$ & $F$ & $T$ \\
    \hline
        $F$ & $T$ & $T$ & $T$ & $F$& $T$ & $F$ \\
    \hline
        $F$ & $F$ & $T$ & $T$ & $T$ & $T$ & $T$ \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{\emph{Truth Table for $P \Rightarrow Q$, $(\neg Q) \Rightarrow (\neg P),$ and $Q \Rightarrow P.$}}
\end{table}

\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some suggestions:

1. Do you really need float `table` in the proof? An unnumbered version (only tabular) is less problematic.

   2. If you use `array` insted of `tabular`, all your dollars inside it are unneeded.
   3. There were some suggestions about packages in comments.

Comment: Thanks. Now, I am getting floats lost as an error message. Is that related to my table?

Comment: @MichaelDykes Probably yes, in your larger document. It would be very strange with the word proof and the table at top of the page, before proof. But `h` as here gives no choice. (And of course you should compile twice, to overwrite your `*.aux` files.

Comment: @PrzemyslawScerwentke: I tried compiling twice and still am getting the: floats lost error in the full document. Specifically: float(s) lost \include{chapter0}

Comment: @MichaelDykes I am afraid that you shuould make MWE from your full document (i.e. cut it to show your float lost problem) and put it as another question. Guessing without knowledge about the rest is rather ineffective.